# I am not able to get dimensions and fact values while browsing cube in SSAS 2005

Tags: ssas, olap, dimensions, cube, fact

I am new to SSAS. I have two tables, FactAnswers and DimDebit. one dimension and one fact. After creating cube when I try to browse dimensions and fact, I got nothing. I want to get AnswerValue from fact table and Debit values from Dim table. Everything you can see in this figure.[image: My Cube]

Please guide me, Where I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you processed the database yet?  That is what actually "loads" data into it...deploying just builds the structure.

Also, are you trying to browse the cube via BIDS, SSMS, Excel, something else?